# Need help to get exact match result using quotes search in sphinx

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

i need your help to solve an issue in Thinking Sphinx.
i am Using 'sphinx-2.0.5-win32' and following gems
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.13' and gem 'riddle', '1.5.3'

sphinx.yml contains
development:
  min_infix_len: 3
  charset_table: "0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, -, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, ., %, @, #, &, *, $"
  binlog_path: '#'

My model file :
Class Rm
  define_index do
    set_property :delta => true
    indexes :code, :as => :rm_code, :sortable => true
    has id
  end
end

---

I am searching like this :
Rm.search Riddle.escape('"rm0001"'), :page => params[:page], :per_page => 25, :match_mode => :extended  -----------> getting 2 results

### Code

rm0001
rm0001N

---

I want only 'rm0001' in search results,
Please help me

Thanks in advance. 
Praveen

Comment: What happens if you don't escape the search query? I'm pretty sure quotes get escaped, and that's not what you want.

Comment: I tried like this, Rm.search '"rm0001"', :match_mode => :extended, but still getting 2 results.I think may be i should define Multiple Indices with ':min_infix_len => 0' and use it.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's definitely the min_infix_len that'll be causing the problem. I guess a second index with that set to zero and then only searching on that index should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You´ve set min_infix_len - which enables part word matches.

But NOT set enable_star=true, which means that querys are automatically part word.

So either remove min_infix_len to disable part word matches, OR set enable_star so that part word matches only happen when include * at star/end of words.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it worked.                                       I got another problem,if i search like this,                                        Rm.search Riddle.escape('1-2-3'), :match_mode => :extended, :star => true,then sphinx search for `*1*-*2*-*3*`, which will give zero results.                                                                                                                                                            If i search with :star => false, it will give correct result.                                       Note: '-' is indexed

Comment: * only work a the beginning/end of a word. Because you have - indexed, its part of a word, so many of those stars are in the middle. without star syntax enabled, you are really looking for '*1-2-3*' the middle stars are not included.

Comment: But - indexed here,so if i use :star => true, sphinx should search for `*1-2-3*` instead of `*1*-*2*-*3*`..right?